# opendiff (FileMerge) on OS X: choose left by default

Tags: macos, difftool, filemerge, opendiff

Can I configure this tool to default the choice for each differing block to the left side rather than the right side?

Right now the workaround is to swap the sides, but this is slightly confusing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not sure I understand what you want to do, but perhaps the following will help. In the `FileMerge.app` UI, as soon as the file comparison window opens, you can press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all the differences (arrows), then press the left arrow key to change them all to the Original file contents. You can then press the up arrow to return to the first change (ignore the `NSBeep()`). Then use the down arrow to cycle down through the diffs and if there's one where you want to change to the "new" content that's showing on the right side, press the right arrow.

Comment: Ah, that is a good shortcut. Yes, this is a great alternative workaround, as now if i have 100 differences and I want to select just one to apply (instead of all of them by default) I can do so without hitting some key 99 times.

Comment: Are there any additional shortcuts apart from **left**, **right** ? For the options: `Choose both (left first)`, `Choose both (right first)`, `Choose neither`